# Finding values of $x,y,z$ in three rows of quadratic equations

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, triangles, quadratics

$x^2+xy+y^2=25$

$x^2+xz+z^2=64$

$y^2+yz+z^2=49$

$x,y,z>0$  $x+y+z=?$

First i have named the rows in order $R_1,R_2,R_3$ as i have tried

$R_3-R_1$   $R_2-R_3$ and  $R_2-R_1$ give reasonable results. Then i had the following

$(z-x).(x+y+z)=24$

$(x-y).(x+y+z)=15$

$(z-y).(x+y+z)=39$

It is obvious that if I add the first two rows it equals to the value of the third row. So i got back to where i started. Maybe the solution can move further from here, i don't know but there is another idea i had.

We know that $\dfrac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\ge\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$ In other words Arithmetic mean is greater or equal to Geometric mean.

Proceeding $x^2+xy+y^2\ge\sqrt[3]{x^3y^3}\rightarrow\dfrac{25}{3}\ge xy$

Using the same method $\dfrac{64}{3}\ge xz$ and $\dfrac{49}{3}\ge yz$

I multiplied these expressions and came to the conclusion that $\dfrac{280}{9}\ge xyz$

$x+y+z\ge 3.\sqrt[3]{xyz}$ Approximately

$x+y+z\ge 11,3313$ That is the approximate value of $\sqrt{129}$

In order to fully solve this problem i need to prove that $x+y+z$ is certainly equal. And my question is this;

How can I do that?

Comment: Reducing this to [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) suggests the following attack. Write $s_1=x+y+z$, $s_2=xy+yz+zx$, $s_3=xyz$, and
$r_1=x^2+xy+y^2$, $r_2=y^2+yz+z^2$, $r_3=z^2+zx+x^2$. Then it is easy to verify that
$$r_1+r_2+r_3=2s_1^2-3s_2,$$
$$r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_1=s_1^4-3s_1^2s_2+3s_2^2.$$
You are given the values of $r_1,r_2,r_3$. And from this pair of equations you should be able to solve $s_1$ by solving $s_2$ from the first and plugging it into the second. Have fun!

Comment: The theory of symmetric polynomials was used in the sense that it gives an algorithm of writing any symmetric polynomial on $x,y,z$, such as $\sum_i r_i$ or $\sum_{i<j} r_ir_j$, in terms of $s_1,s_2,s_3$. That's how I found those equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Delta ABC$ such that $AB=c=7$, $AC=b=8$ and $BC=a=5$.

Easy to see that this triangle is an acute-angled triangle,

which says that there is a point $F$ inside the triangle for which

$\measuredangle AFB=\measuredangle AFB=\measuredangle AFB=120^{\circ}$.

This point names Fermat point of the triangle.

Now, let $FA=z$, $FB=y$ and $FC=x$.

Thus, by law of cosines we obtain your system and we need to find a value of $FA+FB+FC$.

Indeed, by law of cosines again we have $\cos\alpha=\frac{8^2+7^2-5^2}{2\cdot8\cdot7}=\frac{11}{14}$.

We'll use the rotation $R^{60^{\circ}}_{A}$ of $\Delta ABC$ (around $A$ on $60^{\circ}$).

Let $R^{60^{\circ}}_{A}(F)=F'$ and $R^{60^{\circ}}_{A}(C)=C'$.

Thus, since $\Delta AFF'$ is an equilateral triangle,
$$x+y+z=CF+BF+AF=C'F'+BF+FF'=C'F'+F'F+FB=C'B,$$
$AF'=AC=b=8$ and $\measuredangle F'AB=60^{\circ}+\alpha$.

Thus, by law of cosines for $\Delta C'AB$ we obtain: 
$$x+y+z=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(60^{\circ}+\alpha)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{8^2+7^2-2\cdot8\cdot7\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{11}{14}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\frac{5\sqrt3}{14}\right)}=\sqrt{129}.$$
Done!

Comment: Thank you, that is an elegant solution. I'm afraid i couldn't understand completely why you rotated around 60 degrees?

Comment: @Deniz Tuna Yalçın I rotate $\Delta ABC$ because I want to get a value of  $x+y+z$.  I am ready to write a full explanation if you wish.

Comment: I am unfortunately not good enough in algebraic geometry. I would be grateful if you made a full explanation. Thank you

Comment: @Deniz Tuna Yalçın I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you:) the questions i had in mind are now answered:)

Comment: @Deniz Tuna Yalçın You are welcome!

Comment: This is cute, very cute in fact (+1). But AFAICT  it depends heavily on the coincidence that $\cos(2\pi/3)=-1/2$. That's ok for a contest question. I just want to remark that using elementary symmetric polynomials we can equally well handle the case of any symmetric quadratic forms in place of $x^2+xy+y^2$ and cyclic shifts. I tested it with $x^2+3xy+y^2$. The only difference is the need to use three equations (the "dreaded" $r_1r_2r_3$) eventually leading to a quartic equation on $(x+y+z)^2$. This does make the general variant more taxing, but still solvable (finite number of alternatives).

Answer (score 2):

Moving the comments to an answer as a sign of my confidence that the process leads to an answer. This is not a full solution. I'm leaving a bit of the fun for the OP.

Reducing this to [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) suggests the following attack. Write $s_1=x+y+z$, $s_2=xy+yz+zx$, $s_3=xyz$, and
$r_1=x^2+xy+y^2$, $r_2=y^2+yz+z^2$, $r_3=z^2+zx+x^2$. Then it is easy to verify that
$$
\begin{aligned}r_1+r_2+r_3&=2s_1^2-3s_2,\\
r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_1&=s_1^4-3s_1^2s_2+3s_2^2.
\end{aligned}$$
You are given the values of $r_1,r_2,r_3$. And from this pair of equations you should be able to solve $s_1$ by solving $s_2$ from the first and plugging it into the second. Looks like it leads to a biquadratic equation. Hopefully you can eliminate all but one of the alternatives for $s_1$ that pop out.

Comment: The resulting biquadratic gives four choices for $(s_1,s_2)$, but only a single one with $s_1>0,s_2>0$.

Comment: We were a bit lucky in the sense that the expression of $\sum_{i<j}r_ir_j$ did not include $s_3$. If need be, we would have then also used
$$r_1r_2r_3=s_1^2s_2^2-s_2^3-s_1^3s_3,$$ and hoped for the best...

Comment: I checked your way. I think it's nothing. I think it will be better if you'll delete this "solution".

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I had no trouble whatsoever solving the problem with this recipe. The solution $s_1=\sqrt{129}, s_2=40$ sticks out like a sore thumb. Why on earth would I delete this? I'm not one of those "rep-farming calculus experts" who post "hints" without checking that they work. It is borderline insulting to think otherwise. Because this is a contest-math question I didn't want to spell it all out. If you didn't understand some step, you can ask a new question, and I will clarify. FWIW I did win two bronzes at IMOs back in the day.